# Version Control for analytic projects

Tags: git, version-control, analytics

I've found several things about how to manage a data science projet with GIT  but I didn't find something about how to manage a set of projects.

In 90% of the case I'm working alone and over the month a lot of people ask me to check:

- the performance of our marketing operations
- the impact on sales of special period like christmas.
- clustering of our customers
- simple predictive models (churn,...)

**Here is my typical workflow for a single project:**

1. Prepare the data in SQL
2. Make descriptive  and predictive analysis in R/Python. I often use my own  library of code which I update over the time
3. Create output results in Markdown or powerpoint presentation.

**Here is the folder organisation for each project:**

1. Data

   - base
   - processed
2. R scripts
3. Python scripts
4. Outputs *(figures, markdown, powerpoint,...)*

And two libraries of code in R and Python that I use for all the projects.

**Question: In this case what is the best strategy ?**

1. A single repository with  all the projects because the libraries are shared among several projects ?

If yes, is it ok to have dozen of branches in the same repository like:

- `R_library_prod`
- `R_library_dev`
- `Python_library_prod`
- `Python_library_dev`
- `clustering_2015_prod`
- `clustering_2015_dev`
- `christmas_sales_analysis_prod`
- `christmas_sales_analysis_dev`
- *and so on*

  2. A repository for each project ? *(with potentially only 2 branches: prod and dev)*

If yes, how to manage the updates of the R and Python libraries ? Should I have a distinct repo for them and updates the libraries manually in the analytics projects repositories ?

Comment: It seems that programmers fits more with this question : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/286516/version-control-for-several-projects